# Zend tableGateway Model Delete Query with Multiple IDs

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I want to delete multiple rows by TableGateway like below SQL

```
Delete from table where id in (1,2,5,6)  - CSV of multiple ids.
```

Comment: Hi, have you read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If not, you really should, there's important information missing from your question. Could you add: zend documentation related to your issue, what you tried, your expected results, any errors encountered, what you tried to solve said errors? That would help us help you, as SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation at https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-db/table-gateway/
Build a Where object to pass as parameter :

```
$where = new Where();
$where->in('id', [1,2,5,6]);
```